# consumeAsFlow causes app to crash on configuration change

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

I have an activity which loads a list usign paging 3.

I use a channel to emit search text and then consume it as flow to apply transformations to get a flow of List of items

when the app under goes a configuration change I get the following error

```
ReceiveChannel.consumeAsFlow can be collected just once
```

Here is my psuedo code

```kotlin
fun onCreate() {
   lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewModel.skuList.collectLatest {
                adapter.submitData(it)
            }
   }
}
```

In viewModel

```kotlin
val skuList = _searchChannel.consumeAsFlow().flatMapLatest {
        skuRepository.fetchSku(it.activeOrderId, it.supplierId,
            it.name, it.fetchDiscounted, it.skuCategoryIdCombinedText)
        }
    }
```

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ReceiveChannel.consumeAsFlow can be collected just once
       at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.ChannelAsFlow.markConsumed(Channels.kt:130)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.ChannelAsFlow.collect(Channels.kt:153)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.ChannelFlowTransformLatest$flowCollect$3.invokeSuspend(Merge.kt:101)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.ChannelFlowTransformLatest$flowCollect$3.invoke(:8)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.ChannelFlowTransformLatest$flowCollect$3.invoke(:4)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.UndispatchedKt.startUndispatchedOrReturn(Undispatched.kt:89)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.FlowCoroutineKt.flowScope(FlowCoroutine.kt:33)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.ChannelFlowTransformLatest.flowCollect(Merge.kt:25)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.ChannelFlowOperator.collectTo$suspendImpl(ChannelFlow.kt:157)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.ChannelFlowOperator.collectTo()
       at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.ChannelFlow$collectToFun$1.invokeSuspend(ChannelFlow.kt:60)
       at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoop.processUnconfinedEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:69)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DispatchedContinuationKt.resumeCancellableWith(DispatchedContinuation.kt:375)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable(Cancellable.kt:30)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable$default(Cancellable.kt:25)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart.invoke(CoroutineStart.kt:110)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.start(AbstractCoroutine.kt:126)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch(Builders.common.kt:56)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch(:1)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch$default(Builders.common.kt:47)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch$default(:1)
       at com.awantunai.app.home.cart.ordering.add_to_cart.AddToCartV2Activity.setupRecyclerView(AddToCartV2Activity.kt:272)
       at com.awantunai.app.home.cart.ordering.add_to_cart.AddToCartV2Activity.initViews(AddToCartV2Activity.kt:207)
       at com.awantunai.app.home.cart.ordering.add_to_cart.AddToCartV2Activity.onCreate(AddToCartV2Activity.kt:105)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8054)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8034)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1341)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3688)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3864)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:5811)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5703)
       at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute(ActivityRelaunchItem.java:71)
       at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:45)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2253)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7870)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

Comment: The error message explained it itself, you can only collect one time when using `consumeAsFlow`. Use `receiveAsFlow` if you cannot guaranteed that the collection will happen only once which can occur when your Activity gets recreated and depending on your usage of `repeatOnLifecycle`.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround used receiveAsFlow instead of consumeAsFlow

Answer (score 0):

You should be using [repeatOnLifeCycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/package-summary#(androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle).repeatOnLifecycle(androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle.State,kotlin.coroutines.SuspendFunction1)) in order to keep collecting/emiting to your UI after a configuration change

```
// Create a new coroutine since repeatOnLifecycle is a suspend function
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            // The block passed to repeatOnLifecycle is executed when the lifecycle
            // is at least STARTED and is cancelled when the lifecycle is STOPPED.
            // It automatically restarts the block when the lifecycle is STARTED again.
            repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
                // Safely collect from skuList when the lifecycle is STARTED
                // and stops collection when the lifecycle is STOPPED
                lviewModel.skuList.collectLatest {
                    // New skuList
                }
            }
        }
```

You can also take a look at [flowWithLifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/package-summary#(kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow).flowWithLifecycle(androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle,androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle.State))

Comment: It still crashes for me with this, tried both repeatOnLifeCycle and flowWithLifecycle which is just an extenstion function calling repeatOnLifeCycle internally